# Passing a value from UserForm to sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I created a userform called Level with a button, "beginner". When it's clicked "beginner" is set as levelinput as a string to be used in coding sheet 1

--------------Sheet1(Code)------------

```
Public levelInput as string

Public Sub Player()
Level.show
Msgbox levelInput

Lev=levelInput
.....

end sub
```

--------------Below is for Userform, Levels------------------

```
Private Sub beginner_Click()
levelInput= "beginner"
Levels.Hide
end sub
```

Currently, the msgbox shows nothing and the value doesn't seem to be passed to the Sheet(Code).

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is the scope of the variable levelInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> levelInput= "beginner"
> ```

That variable isn't declared. I know, you *think* it is, but I'll get to it in a moment.

The thing you've fallen pray of, is called *scoping*.

> ```
> Public levelInput as string
> ```

By declaring the `levelInput` public field in the code-behind of `Sheet1`, you're saying "any *instance* of `Sheet1` will have a `levelInput` public variable".

So you can change your code to this:

```
Sheet1.levelInput= "beginner"
```

And it will work.

But the most important thing to do is this:

```
Option Explicit
```

Always turn that option on, in the *declarations section* of every module (i.e. at the top, before any `Sub` or `Function` or `Property`). Had you done that, the VBA compiler would have told you `levelInput` isn't declared, and would have refused to run anything until you fixed the problem - either by declaring a locally-scoped `levelInput` variable, or by properly qualifying the `Sheet1.levelInput` public field.

Without `Option Explicit`, VBA happily lets you assign and refer to variables that aren't declared, which leads to unexpected bug, as you've experienced.

---

<sub>PS - Once you get your code to work as intended, I'd recommend you post it on [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com), where you'll learn things like why `Level.Show` is bad code, and how you can use functions, parameters and return values instead of global variables, for more robust, maintainable and easier-to-follow code.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. I must say, your explanation is better than my professor's:))